# How to subtract 2 integers within a string

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am probably just tackling this the wrong way but at line 2 I am trying to subtract 2 user inputs within a print string.

BTW this is just for a nim sum game, where the user chooses the amount and goes first, then plays the computer.

```
def setup(startamt, userturn):
    print(str("there are " + startamt - userturn + " balls left"))

def main():
    startamt = input("How many balls do you want to start with?(15 or more) ")
    userturn = input("How many balls will you take?(1-4) ")
    setup(startamt, userturn)
```

Comment: You must cast the `startamt` and `userturn` to `int`, Currently they are of `str` type

Comment: @Zdar, why do you answer in comments and not in "Your Answer" section?

Comment: @MaksimKneller Some questions have minor errors or corrections which can be explained in one-liners So I prefer the comment section and preserve the Answers section for special questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that `input()` returns a string (`str`) object, so to do a calculation you need to convert them to integers (`int()`) or floating point (`float()`) numbers.

Since you are on 3.6 then you can use *Literal string interpolation*.  For example:

```
startamt = "52"
userturn = "9"
print(f"there are {str(int(startamt) - int(userturn))} balls left")
```

The preceding `f` indicates we are using interpolation, which is done inside the `{  }`.

Comment: thank you,  I lied unintentionally, I use 3.5

Comment: @JoshP:  that's OK, you have this feature to look forward to then :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your second line, the `startamt - userturn` are each being evaluated as strings.

You can either do:

```
print("there are " + int(startamt) - int(userturn) + " balls left"))
```

or using string formatting which is more Pythonic:

```
print("there are {} balls left".format(int(startamt) - int(userturn)))
```

Comment: `startamt` and `userturn` are strings.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks, I updated to cast as ints.

Comment: @JoshP, did you cast each one to int() ? Can you edit your post and add your new code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
def setup(startamt, userturn):

    print("there are", str((int(startamt) - int(userturn))), "balls left"

def main():
    startamt = input("How many balls do you want to start with?(15 or more) ")
    userturn = input("How many balls will you take?(1-4) ")
    setup(startamt, userturn)


main()
```